# What does Dualcast do if my Orb Slots are empty?

Tags: slay-the-spire

The description for the Dualcast card says it will "Evoke your next orb twice". Normally this would evoke your rightmost Orb immediately. What does Dualcast do if your Orb Slots are empty? Does the card get wasted, or does the effect get delayed until an Orb slot gets filled?

[image: Dualcast with empty orb slots]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing a Dualcast card when all Orb Slots are empty will have no effect. You will pay the energy needed for the card, but nothing else happens.